# VBScript [Used to export from one program to the excel]

Tags: excel, vbscript

To summarize what I need, I will start with simple explanation:

I am using .vbs script to export from "E3 Zucken" software to excel template.

One of the exported columns in excel is getting this value which is being pulled from E3 Zucken:

[image: size of the wire]

I have, maybe, 10 different wire sizes and the problem is that I need an if statement in .vbs script to detect which wire size is getting pulled and base on the wire size it should set the "font" size according to the wire size.

Currently I have this line in my .vbs script that puts the font size automatically to 5 which is not suitable for all wire sizes that I have:

```
Excel.Cells(nline, 50).Value = "5"    '"A1Font"
```

Is it possible to set this value according to the wire size?

Comment: Please [don’t post your code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/692942).

Comment: Recommend reading [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/9t9x467f(v=vs.84)) to learn about the types if conditional statements available in VBScript. Would recommend using a [`Select Case` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/6ef9w614(v=vs.84)) over an `If` for this scenario.

Comment: Alright, thanks.
But I am not even sure from where should I start with this one.

Should I just put "Select Case" under that line with font?
Also, how will my .vbs script detect if I have 0.35mm wire or 4mm wire. In case if it is 0.35mm wire then font should be 5 and in case of a 4mm wire the font should be 7.

Current export give me value of 5 for all wire sizes and then I have to manually change it in excel which takes a lot of time to do.

Answer (score 0):

A re-usable approach would be to build a function that encapsulates the conditional logic, something like this, by using a `Dictionary` we can build up a list of wire sizes as keys and the font size as the value of the entry;

```
Function DetermineFontSize(wire_size)
    Const default_size = 5
    If Len(wire_size & "") < 1 DetermineFontSize = default_size 'Guard clause
    Dim list: Set list = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Call list.Add("FLRYW-B-0.35_BK", 5) 
    ... 'Assumed other entries
    Call list.Add("FLRYW-B-4.00_BK", 7)
    If Not list.Exists(wire_size) Then DetermineFontSize = default_size
    DetermineFontSize = list(wire_size).Value
End Function
```

You would call it by passing the wire size value into the `Function`.

```
Excel.Cells(nline, 50).Value = DetermineFontSize(your_wire_size)
```